# How can I scrape information that is in the parameters of an AJAX page using Selenium or Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the coordinates of this project in the map from this website: https://www.iproperty.com.my/new-property/property/sentul/m-arisa/new-6029/.

I realized that the information that I need is in the XHR request body as such:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiPG.png)

How can I extract the coordinates that is in the request parameters programmatically? I need to do this so that I can iterate through the listings on this website and extract all the locations of new projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the code source of the page, and search for : 3.207
There you will see something like :

[image]

If you get at the beginning of the line you'll have something like

```
window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {...
```

So I see a few solutions here :

- Craft a regular expression to get those coordinates from the source of the webpage.
- Run some javascript on the webpage to get the data you need :

```
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__.detail.address
```

yields :

```
Object { formattedAddress: "Sentul, Kuala Lumpur", lat: 3.207275, lng: 101.689752, hasLatLng: true, hideMarker: false }
```